# How to get a menu of sys_categories with a link to an extension listview

Tags: typo3

I've build an extension to handle some products similar to a shop extension but more as a catalogue. Now I've build in the category-tree the complete menu structure. In the product - Create - Mask i can set the categories to the product.

So first: How can i give out in the FE a normal `<ul><li></li></ul>` menu structure of the whole sys_categorie-tree?

And second: How can i put the link into the menu of each category to show the content who has this category.

Answer (score 1):

There is example extension [`categories_example`](https://github.com/digicademy/categories_example) available by *Torsten Schrade* showing how you *can* build trees on own plugins and eventually link the items, just install it, test and the adopt required parts into your own extension.

*Note:* It's not available in TYPO3 TER, anyway you can just download ZIP from github, unzip it into `typo3conf/ext/`, rename `categories_example-master` to `categories_example` and then activate extension within *Extension Manager*. It's (probably for historical reasons) marked as compatible only with TYPO3 `6.1.0-6.1.99` versions, anyway this code is *non-destructive*, so you can safely force installation on higher versions as well.

Comment: OK, thx I'll try this. I don't know if I can separate the relevant code. First you have to know which this is. I'll come back if i come through.